# How do I properly set my background position when working with a sprited image?

Tags: css, sprite

I am working on the nav element of my website and I wanted to add some images as clickable links in a vertical list that could be used as my navigation element:

```
<nav>
    <ul style="display:inline">
        <li style="height: 12px; width:34px; background: url(backgroundsprite.gif) 0 0;"></li>
    </ul>
<nav>
```

The code above works and shows what I want it to show(one part of the sprite,The home image) when I set the background position coordinates to 0 0. But if I set the coordinates to anything else, the image doesn't show up. How can I properly show the different parts of the sprited image?

attached is the image I am working with.

[image: Sprite containing the menu elements]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify `background-position` the same way as if you specify `left` and `top` for the element with `position: relative`.

E. g. if you need to move the element up for 10px you'd set `top: -10px`.
The same way you move the background:

```css
a {
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
  margin-top:3px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1GGF.gif);
}

a[href='home.html'] {
  width: 38px;
  background-position: -36px 0;
}

a[href='aboutme.html'] {
  width: 60px;
  background-position: 0 -18px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="home.html"></a>
  <a href="aboutme.html"></a>
<nav>
```

But I'd strongly recommended you using text instead of picture of the text. It would give you benefits: easy changing of the text itself and its font properties, better for SEO and for screenreaders.

Also I simplified your code, probably you'll find it useful too.